# Strong rules for the elastic net

Tags: lasso, regularization, elastic-net

In their paper ([here](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ftp/strong.pdf)), Tibshirani et al defined the lasso as the solution
to
$$
\text{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert ^{2}+\lambda\left\Vert \boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert _{1}
$$
and give the sequential strong rule for the lasso coefficients being zero as
$$
\left|\mathbf{x}_{j}^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\left(\lambda_{k-1}\right)\right)\right|<2\lambda_{k}-\lambda_{k-1}
$$
with $\lambda_{0}=\lambda_{\text{max}}=\max_{j}\left|\mathbf{x}_{j}^{T}\mathbf{y}\right|$.

The elastic net is a special form of the lasso as
$$
\text{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert \tilde{\mathbf{y}}-\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert ^{2}+\lambda\alpha\left\Vert \boldsymbol{\beta}\right\Vert _{1}
$$
with
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{X}}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}\\
\sqrt{\lambda\left(1-\alpha\right)}\mathbf{I}
\end{pmatrix},\quad\tilde{\mathbf{y}}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{y}\\
\mathbf{0}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
They give the strong rules for the elastic net as
$$
\left|\mathbf{x}_{j}^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\left(\lambda_{k-1}\right)\right)\right|<\alpha\left(2\lambda_{k}-\lambda_{k-1}\right)
$$

My problem:

When I put the expressions of $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}$
into the strong rule of the lasso, I could not get this expression
of strong rule of elastic net.

Instead, I got
$$
\left|\mathbf{x}_{j}^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\left(\lambda_{k-1}\right)\right)+\lambda\left(1-\alpha\right)\mathbf{x}_{j}^{T}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\left(\lambda_{k-1}\right)\right|<\alpha\left(2\lambda_{k}-\lambda_{k-1}\right)
$$
Where is my mistake?